# Themes for using jQuery Mobile on non-mobile sites

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, themes

I like jQuery Mobile for being a complete package for designing not only Mobile sites, but websites in general.  I like it because its included layouts and page transition system are cool.

Does anyone have experience using it on jQuery Mobile on non-mobile sites?  Are there any good themes to use for non-mobile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'd be better off to use JQuery UI and the accompanying ThemeRoller:

JQuery UI:
http://jqueryui.com/home

Themeroller:
http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/

Comment: You are right.  I had worked with Mobile before JQuery UI.  I didn't understand that that is where the whole theme stuff came from.